# GWT: Additional <br> tags on RichTextArea.getHTML() in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, gwt, rich-text-editor, richtextarea

I have a `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RichTextArea` with text "*Hello World*".
When I do:

**IE / CHROME**

```
String text = richTextArea.getText(); // I get "Hello World" - CORRECT
String value = richTextArea.getHTML();  // I get "Hello World" - CORRECT
```

**FIREFOX**

```
String text = richTextArea.getText(); // I get "Hello World" - CORRECT
String value = richTextArea.getHTML();  // I get "Hello World<br>" - INCORRECT
```

Any Ideas?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GWT issue logged for this - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6798

Work Around -  Sanitize the html string -

```
Class MyRichTextArea extends RichTextArea{
       public String getHTML() {
        return super.getHTML().equals("<br>") ? "" : super.getHTML();
    }
}
```

This is not exactly a GWT specific bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that this issue has been already reported as a bug. Meanwhile, we can get around this with a code like this:

```
String value = richTextArea.getHTML();
if(value.lastIndexOf("<br>") == value.length()-4)
  value = value.substring(0, value.length()-4);
```